# I am getting an error When I type 'pip install dlib-19.19.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl' into my comand prompt

Tags: python-3.x, command-prompt

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrnoM.png)

I am trying to install dlib how do i do it and why am i getting this erroraaa aa a

Comment: What are your Windows and Python versions?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the error message *as text* instead of linking to a picture?

Answer (score 0):

The wheel you are trying to use is built for CPython 3.7 (`cp37`) on 64-bit ms-windows (`win_amd64`).

Given the following error message:

> dlib-19.19.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

There are two most important possible causes:

- you are not using CPython 3.7, or
- your windows installation is 32-bit, not 64-bit.

Looking at [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/dlib/#files), there don't seem to be wheels for the latest version available.

You could try running `pip install dlib`.